# Error serializing cookies returned from getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working ON Reactjs and i am using nextjs, I used cookie for login module but now i am getting following error
Error serializing `.cookies` returned from `getServerSideProps` Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.
Also i want to know how can we remove cookie value during logout, I have following code for login module

```
const email = response.data.email
Cookies.set('email', email )
```

And here is my serversideprops code

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context: { req: { headers: { cookie: any; }; }; }) {
    
  const cookies = context.req.headers.cookie;
  if (cookies) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        permanent: false,
        destination: "/dashboard",
      },
      props:{},
    };
  }
  
  return {
    props: {
      cookies,
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the error `undefined cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use null or omit this value` occurred because `cookie` isn't always there when the script. an easy fix would be

```js
...
return {
    props: {
      cookies: cookies || null,
    },
  };
...
```